# Check if two variables are equal from three choices

Tags: python

I have three integers, and I need to check if two of them are equal. The code I have is quite ugly:

```
a = 5
b = 7
c = 5
if a == b or b == c or a == b:
    pass
```

I wonder if there is a better alternative to this kind of comparation.

Comment: what do you mean by "In my real example, the integers are other thing longer"?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf this is just an example, in my real program the variables are lists but it is not relevant

Comment: A bit cryptic but shorter, `len({a, b, c}) < 3`

Comment: @DanielMesejo won't work with lists which are OP real usecase

Comment: @DeepSpace you are right, can convert to tuples

Comment: @DanielMesejo Assuming the lists don't contain unhashable values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just build a `set` and check the resulting length:

```
a = 5
b = 7
c = 5

if len({a,b,c}) < 3:
    pass
```

---

Since you mention in your real case the variables are lists, you could convert them to `tuples` which are hashable and hence can build a set from them. So instead you could do:

```
a = [5, 2]
b = [7, 2]
c = [5, 2]

if len(set(map(tuple, [a,b,c]))) < 3:
    pass
```

Comment: You can use set literal so you don't build and throw away a list (`{a,b,c}`) but it does not matter since OP's variables are unhashable lists

Comment: or in general:

`lst = [a, b, c];`

`len(set(lst)) < len(lst)`

Comment: True thanks for pointing out @DeepSpace . Lists? Is that mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Oh I see its mentioned in the comments @DeepSpace

Answer (score 2):

Because you are having lists, you won't be able to use a set directly. If so, you will get an error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Convert your lists to tuples, then use the following:

```
if len(set([tuple(a),tuple(b), tuple(c)])) < 3:
    pass
```